# Laravel Nested resources and re-usable controllers

Tags: php, rest, laravel, laravel-4

I am creating an API and I want to include both regular resources and nested resources

For example, I will say I have a `Post` resource and `Comment` resource. I have setup the appropriate routes and controllers like the following

**Routes**

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsControllers'); // /posts/{id}
Route::resource('comments', 'CommentsControllers'); /comments/{id}
```

But I also want to have comments as a nested resource of posts, like this

**Nested resource route**

```
Route::resource('posts.comments', 'PostCommentsControllers'); /posts/{id}/comments/{id}
```

Because I have already written my `CommentsController`, I would like to know of the best method to re-use the `CommentsController` for my `PostsController`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using inheritance is the best way:

```
class BaseController extends Controller {

    public function index() {

    }   

    public function create() {

    }       

    public function store() {

    }       

    public function update() {

    }       

}

class PostsController extends BaseController {

}

class CommentsController extends BaseController {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I figured that extend a base class. An issue I saw is for example with the store() method. For the parent resource the signature would look like this: store($id) but in the nested resource it would look like: store($parent_id, $id) but that majority of the logic would be the same

Answer (score 0):

You can just extend your Blog/Comment/*Controller on a generic FooBarController which holds all the logic.

You will have to supply the model and other model-related data, I do this via the constructor, and my models holding data about the columns, etc.